# Forcing image size in a post

Tags: css, wordpress

I am using a feed aggregating website. Sometimes I get post such as this: http://food101.co.il/%D7%90%D7%95%D7%98%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%A0%D7%92%D7%99-%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%94-%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D/

Where the image is larger than the text-box of the post. Here is a screen shot:
[image]

Is there a way to make sure in the css of the site that this too-large-to-fit image will be re-sized in some way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I definitely wouldn't use `max-width`, and especially not `width` directly on the `img` selector. You then affect every image on your site.

Use something more specific like `.entry-content img { max-width: 500px; }`

That will target any image posted in a post or article.

Answer (score 2):

you just need to edit your css style and fix one measure (in this case, the width is better), so your image will get scaled to fit that value

```
img {
    width: <value_here>
}
```

if you don't specify your height, image will be resized and mantain scale accordingly. you can also specify a max-width, so that little images won't loose quality